# How to deploy QT program on another computer without QT Creator in window platform

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, window, platform

How to deploy QT program on another computer without QT Creator

The program I packed with QT creator (with various dynamic library files) cannot run on another computer without QT creator installed in window platform

Comment: Please edit your question with an actual error demonstrating that it cannot run, the output of dependencies.exe for your program, as well as the files you *did* ship.

Comment: ***How to deploy QT program on another computer without QT Creator in window platform*** Since 2008 when I started developing with Qt at work I use CMake and CPack + my own scripts however that is not the only way. Qt has an installer framework which many people use. [https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html)

Comment: Read this https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

*(Microsoft Windows Specific)*
Your application is not running on another machine without Qt installed because you are not including all the Qt dynamic link libraries that are required to run it.

Qt has a tool (see more in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html) that will find all the required dll's for you, and add them to your build directory automatically.  *Alternatively you could just copy ALL the .dll files in your Qt's installation folder by hand, but you will end up with way more than you need.*

To use this you should run the following from a cmd prompt:
`"C:<path to your Qt intall/compiler name>/bin/windeployqt.exe" "<path to your build executable including file name>.exe"`

For example (change the qt version, your compiler, and project name as necessary):
`"C:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/bin/windeployqt.exe" "C:/Repositories/build-MyApp-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Release/release/MyApp.exe"`

This can also be automated if you do this frequently by adding to your project's build steps.  To do this:

1. Open the "Projects" tab on the left hand side of Qt Creator.
2. Select the build configuration you would like to use (for example, I would take the 'Release" configuration, copy it, and name it "Windows Deploy").
3. Under "Build Steps" click on "Add Build Step" and select "Custom Process Step".
4. Give the new step the following values:
   **Command**: cmd.exe
   **Arguments**: /c "%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_BINS}/windeployqt.exe" %{CurrentRun:Executable:FilePath}
   **Working directory**:%{buildDir}